# Will the Rome Marathon make it hard to get to my hotel?

Tags: italy, transportation, taxis, rome

We arrive in Rome during the Rome marathon. Our hotel is inside the route by a block or two. Will we be able to cross the street to get to our hotel or will we have to find some official crossing? I assume the taxi will not be allowed to cross the marathon route. How big a hassle will this be?

More info as requested: My hotel, [Hotel Hiberia](http://www.hotelhiberia.com), is on Via XXIV Maggio, 8 - 00187. That seems to be just inside Kilometer 41.5 according to [The Rome Marathon site](https://www.maratonadiroma.it/?!a/=/en-117-route/). Our plane lands at FCO at 9:45 local time.

Comment: Presumably crossing won't be a problem as long as you find a point where there is adequate space between runners for you not to interfere with the race.  Vehicles will likely be banned on and very near the route so expect to walk a couple of blocks or so.

Comment: I have never been in Rome, so also not during the marathon. I have been in Rotterdam and there the whole of the route is strictly closed and the only ways into  the enclosed area is where there are bridges or tunnels crossing the route. (Of which there are a few.)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think it might be difficult, and nearly impossible, but do not dispair!

I would ask your hotel; they will be in a better position to tell you how to do it; it is surely not the first time it happens. 
[Rome Marathon information](https://www.maratonadiroma.it/?!a/=/race-day-info-/)

The start time is at 8h40am (up to 8h52-ish). The best runners will arrive around 10h50am; the bulk of the runners will be arriving for at least the next hours up to 13h40-ish (4-5 hours marathon).

The marathon officially lasts 7h30; the last road to open will be near your hotel.

Your plane lands at 9h45, it takes about 1 hour to get your belongings, and takes around 45 minutes to get to Termini train station. I imagine that if you take a taxi it will be easier to drop you there); so you will be "near" your hotel at around 11h30am. You will have to walk to your hotel.

Normally at events like that, there are officials posted at street intersections, police persons, voluntary persons... I would seek one out and ask them if it is possible to cross the street, usually with the assistance of the officials.

Good luck, if all fails, just find yourself (beforehand) a good cafe or bar and get your first coffee or Spritz and just chill.

Comment: This. Also recognize that the runners do have the right of way, so if a hole does open up you will have to hustle -- not amble -- across.

Comment: That is why it best to ask a race official when wanting to cross the street.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. My co-travelers want to go straight to the hotel to nap after the red-eye flight. I like the idea of a visit to a bar for a drink. I think the Museum of Rome near Termini station might be a good choice since I think they have a luggage check. I'll be too excited to nap anyway.